# No more than a word puzzle

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix is just starting to grow.
> My infix has almost formed an opinion.
> My suffix is going to receive.
> My whole is limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word is

> BUDGET

My prefix is just starting to grow.

> BUD

My infix has almost formed an opinion.

> BUDGE

My suffix is going to receive.

> GET

My whole is limited.

> Budgets are limited.